# Assign an Object to an animated rig

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones

Imported a rigged mesh from mixamo into blender. Fixed the animation because I wasnt able to see the actual animation, including keyframes by deselecting the option "import with skin". But now I`ve got the rigged bones only. These plays the animation but without my model which should do the anim. How can I attatch the model to the bones? Tried it with a child but didnt work.
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: yeah of course https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/M2XnmK3V

Comment: The mesh is not parented but anyway your armature seems incomplete, the bones don't seem to match the limbs etc...

Comment: Idea how I can solve this?

Comment: I doubt you can get anything from these armature and actions as the original bones are missing (I can't see them either with Alt H or in the armature layers), maybe someone will tell...

Comment: Ok bro. Now I got my rig for the right character installed. How can I apply the animation on the rig?

Comment: "Now I got my rig for the right character installed", what do you mean? Do you have a correct armature? In that case you just need to parent with Ctrl P > With Automatic Weight. But you won't get anything correct from the armature you've shared